# How to make UIView's width increase when a upload percentage increases? SWIFT 4

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, uiview, swift4

I have a project that uploads multiple images to Firebase, and have made a constant that calculates the percentage of the current upload progress:

```
uploadTask.observe(.progress, handler: { (snapshot) in
                guard let progress = snapshot.progress else {
                    return
                }

                let percentage = (Float(progress.completedUnitCount) / Float(progress.totalUnitCount))
                progressBlock(Double(percentage))
            })
```

I have made a UIView element but have not connected it. I am trying to make the UIView acts as a progress bar for the user to visibly see how the upload is progressing. I have been trying to do this but have been unsuccessful at it. How can I do this? By the way: The UIView should be increasing as the `percentage` increases, and at 100% the UIView will reset and hide.

Thank you so much!

Comment: This is not a "tell me how to code my app idea" site. This is a site to get help debugging code you've written yourself.

Answer (score 2):

Create a custom subclass of `UIView`. Give the custom subclass a property `percentComplete`.

Have the view use a `CAShapeLayer` to draw a filled area that expands to fill the view as the percentage value increases from 0.0 to 1.0. (You could also override the `drawRect()` method and use Quartz drawing, but shape layers are easier and more performant.

Do some searching on `CAShapeLayer` for ideas on how to do that.

You can either have your view add a shape layer as an additional layer on the view, or you can have your view provide a `layerClass` property that causes the view's content layer to be a single `CAShapeLayer`

Answer (score 0):

Here is the code to change width of your view dynamically.

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {


    var widthAnchor:NSLayoutConstraint!
    let perecentageView:UIView={
        let view = UIView()
        view.backgroundColor = .red
        view.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false//Its needed becasue we are using anchors
        return view
    }()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        self.view.addSubview(perecentageView)
        perecentageView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.view.topAnchor, constant: 100).isActive = true
        perecentageView.leftAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.view.leftAnchor, constant: 10).isActive = true
        perecentageView.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 50).isActive = true
        widthAnchor = perecentageView.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 0) // By default its 0
        widthAnchor.isActive = true

        self.uploadProgess()

    }


    func uploadProgess(){
        uploadTask.observe(.progress, handler: { (snapshot) in
            guard let progress = snapshot.progress else {
                return
            }

            let percentage = (Float(progress.completedUnitCount) / Float(progress.totalUnitCount))


            let newWidth = self.view.frame.width * percentage / 100
            DispatchQueue.main.async(execute: {
                self.widthAnchor.constant = newWidth
               // self.view.frame.width is the parent view (And max width will be = self.view.frame.width)
               //if you are using view from storybard with aoutolayout then just take IBOutlet of view's with and here widthAnchor = your IBOutlet

                /*
                 if you are using view from storybard and without autolayout then use below code
                 self.perecentageView.frame = CGRect(x: self.perecentageView.frame.origin.x, y: self.perecentageView.frame.origin.y, width: newWidth, height: self.perecentageView.frame.height)
                 */
            })


        })
    }


}
```